# The source workstation is empty in Windows Logs. How to find it?

Tags: authentication, windows

First, I apologise if  I selected a wrong thread for this question.

I receive lots of login failures on a DC for an account called as a domain. So obviously instead of a username, someone put there a domain name. And I'm trying to figure out the source of login failures and remediate it.

Please see blow Windows error messages:

```
> <13>May 30 09:07:43 192.168.1.1(<- IP address of a DC) AgentDevice=WindowsLog
> AgentLogFile=Security    Source=Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing   
> Computer=my_domain_controller.mydomain.local    User=    Domain=    EventID=4625   
> EventIDCode=4625    EventType=16    EventCategory=12544   
> RecordNumber=1496134876135    TimeGenerated=1496134771119   
> TimeWritten=1496134771119    Message=An account failed to log on.   
> Subject:   Security ID:  S-1-0-0   Account Name:  -   Account Domain: 
> -   Logon ID:  0x0    Logon Type:   3    Account For Which Logon Failed:   Security ID:  S-1-0-0   Account Name:  mydomain   Account
> Domain:      Failure Information:   Failure Reason:  %%2313   Status: 
> 0xc000006d   Sub Status:  0xc0000064    Process Information:   Caller
> Process ID: 0x0   Caller Process Name: -    Network Information:  
> Workstation Name:    Source Network Address: -   Source Port:  -   
> Detailed Authentication Information:   Logon Process:  NtLmSsp   
> Authentication Package: NTLM   Transited Services: -   Package Name
> (NTLM only): -   Key Length:  0



> <13>May 30 09:07:43 192.168.1.1(<- IP address of a DC) AgentDevice=WindowsLog
> AgentLogFile=Security    Source=Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing   
> Computer=my_domain_controller.mydomain.local    User=    Domain=    EventID=4776   
> EventIDCode=4776    EventType=16    EventCategory=14336   
> RecordNumber=1496134876135    TimeGenerated=1496134775413   
> TimeWritten=1496134775413    Message=The computer attempted to
> validate the credentials for an account.    Authentication Package:
> MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0  Logon Account: mydomain 
> Source Workstation:   Error Code: 0xc0000064
```

In this logs, the source IP is DC's IP (it's OK though). But the 'Workstation Name' is empty. However, Logon Type: 3 indicates that it is a network logon. So I could not find where it comes from.

I thought that it might be an RDP connection over SSL/TLS, but in this case, NTLM should not be in use. Is that correct?

Or maybe these are authentication attempts over IIS? But why I have so few of information?

Or... So I really do not know what it could be and how to stop it.

Maybe some additional audit policy might give here more information?

Will enable additional "NTLM auditing", it maybe give me more information.

Any advice?

Comment: what is computer.domain.com?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that it is a DC name.

Comment: And isn't it enough to know the IP of the workstation?

Comment: That is only IP address of the DC. I don't know IP of the workstation.

Comment: A, I understand it now, so you didn't mask it in log. Its hard to find something in obfuscated log...

Comment: From documentation: Source Network Address: The IP address of the computer where the user is physically present in most cases unless this logon was initiated by a server application acting on behalf of the user. If this logon is initiated locally the IP address will sometimes be 127.0.0.1 instead of the local computer's actual IP address.  This field is also blank sometimes because Microsoft says "Not every code path in Windows Server 2003 is instrumented for IP address, so it's not always filled out."

Comment: So it seems the action was not taken from workstation even not from localhost as otherwise the IP would be there. It seems to me you have some app or service somewhere and credentials were not passed correctly to its config. I would say it can also be related to RDP. Try this: https://serverfault.com/questions/683837/event-id-4625-without-source-ip

Comment: By the way, the question is related more to serverfault.com than to security

Comment: Just try and let us know if you found it.